# How to select names using link table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, linktable

So I have a check to see if you're allowed to view that folder(currently checking if the ip is my home ip)

I want this check updated into checking if your account has the rights. So i want to get all the names from gallery_folders where user_id = :user_id (yes pdo, but that doesn't matter for this)

```
SELECT      f.name 
FROM        gallery_folders     as f 
LEFT JOIN   gallery_link        as p 
WHERE       f.id = p.folder_id
AND         p.user_id = :user_id
```

This is where I got stuck, I'm not sure how to add `user_id` to this so it'll only get all the `(p.folder_id where user_id=:user_id)`

Databse structure if necessary:

Folders

- gallery_folders

  - id
  - name

Users

- gallery_users

  - id
  - username
  - password
  - token

Link table

- gallery_link

  - id
  - user_id
  - gallery

Comment: in the last `and user_id=:user_id)`

Comment: Take a look at a beginners guide orr tutorial or something

Comment: You are not showing the `gallery_permissions` table structure.  Instead you show  `gallery_link`.  Is that supposed to be `gallery_permissions`?  Also, it should be `ON f.id=p.folder_id` and not `WHERE f.id=p.folder_id`.

Comment: @Linger yes it was a mistake i'll update it now with the query change i just made

Comment: Change your `WHERE` to `ON` and your `AND` to `WHERE`.  Does `folder_id` exist in `gallery_link`?  Have you even tried running the query, or just guessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the folders where the user has the proper rights then you will want to change the join from `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.  You also need to fix your join statement so that it is `ON f.id = p.folder_id` instead of `WHERE f.id = p.folder_id`.

I think this is what you are after:

```
SELECT f.name 
FROM gallery_folders f 
INNER JOIN gallery_link p 
ON f.id = p.folder_id
WHERE p.user_id = :user_id
```